# Looking for a HTML5 / Javascript PDF Page Flipper

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, flip

I'm looking for a non-Flash 'page flipper' that is capable of displaying PDFs. The example I've been given (in Flash) is: http://www.mitsubishi-motors.nl/digital/1043/index/book/outlanderbrochure.aspx

I looked into Uniflip but it seems to be Flash only. FlipBook looks decent (jQuery) but doesn't seem to support PDFs.

We can afford to pay for this, but we don't have time to build it ourselves. Does anyone know of anything out there?

Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mozilla has been working on a JS-only PDF renderer for a while:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Here's a demo of it in action:

http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

But this is a proof-of-concept HTML5 library and it is cutting-edge. If you need to support a lot of browsers, you're stuck with Flash or rendering the PDF as graphics, neither of which is an attractive option.

Comment: Ah, I feared it was a bit 'soon'. I did see that project but after looking at the source I think it would take a decent amount of time to implement the page animations on top of it. Probably would be a nice side project for someone enterprising though, I suspect a lot of corporate websites will be looking for things like this in the near future with Flash going the way of the Dodo. Thanks for your answer, anyway :)

Comment: actually, on the [gallery of modifications page](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Gallery-of-user-projects-and-modifications) they have a link to a working "Page flip effect" demo based on turn.js v3 - and turn.js v4 has zoom but it is unfortunate v4 is not open source :(

Comment: @afshin And where is curl/flip effect?!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a perfect match, but if you haven't seen them yet, check out:

1. [Mozilla's PDF renderer in JavaScript](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)
2. [Scribd's viewer is now in HTML5](http://www.scribd.com), as is [SlideShare's](http://www.slideshare.net). Maybe their commercial offering will work for you
3. [DocumentCloud](http://www.documentcloud.org/) may have something you can use, or have the expertise to build it for you the way you want